# Retweeting only tweets with media with tweepy in python

Tags: python, twitter, bots, tweepy

Recently I've been working to develop a bot. But I got stuck for retweeting only media tweets and not the texts. So is there any way to filter them out?
here is my part of code with liking and retweeting.

```
for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, search).items(nrTweets):
try:
    i += 1
    print(str(i) + '. Tweet Liked')
    tweet.favorite()
    time.sleep(30)
    print(str(i) + '. Retweeted')
    tweet.retweet()
    os.system('cls')
except tweepy.TweepError as e:
    print(e.reason)
except StopIteration:
    break
```

Answer (score 0):

To check if a tweet has media attached to it, you can use the entities object. You would access the entities object, then check if there is a "media" key under it. When you get the tweet, you can try `tweet.entities["media"]`. If it there's media attached with a tweet, it would return information about the media, and if not, it would throw a KeyError.

For your scenario, you could put `tweet.entities["media"]` under your try statement so if no error occurs, it means that media does exist and you can continue to like/retweet that tweet. For the KeyError, you should add another except statement catching the error to skip liking/retweeting that tweet.

```
try:
    media = tweet.entities["media"]
    # like & retweet the tweet
except KeyError:
    print("Skipping tweet -- no media.")
# your other except statements
```

Here's the docs on the Twitter API's entities object: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/data-dictionary/object-model/entities#entitiesobject